# Filtered reference list in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I Have the following Table as a source list:

[image]

And I would like to get the following list as a result:

[image]

The Criteria should be a variable so I can filter for different criteria on different output lists.

Thanks for the support.

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't use "Filters" it's already built-in to Excel?

Comment: Yes, as the goal of using the formula is to automate an accounting task which requires the employees to be separated into different tabs, depending on certain criteria. If I only wanted to do this once, it would not be a problem to use the filters, however this task needs to be performed daily, so the formula option really saves a lot of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MINIFS should do what you want (in your simple example anyway).

```
=IF(
    MINIFS($A$1:$A$7, $B$1:$B$7, $F$1,$A$1:$A$7,">"&MAX($F$1:$F1))=0,
    "",
    MINIFS($A$1:$A$7,$B$1:$B$7,$F$1,$A$1:$A$7,">"&MAX($F$1:$F1))
)
```

[image]

Comment: Don't you have to duplicate the formula multiple times?

Comment: ? no. just set the ranges with absolute references and you can just drag the formula down as far as you need.

Comment: Dragging the formula down is duplicating the formula...Pretty much you have to place a formula in every cell. Where this takes up a lot more resources. (just as a FYI)

Comment: Anyhow, I am glad to see that the OP found that this was acceptable. Granted I never said it wasn't acceptable, it just requires duplication (which in my opinion it is best to avoid heavy resource tasks).

Comment: @irwinallen13 if the op requires a list of results (in separate cells), without resorting to VBA, then you are required to duplicate the formula in each of the cells in the list as a minimum. To my knowledge, no built in formula can affect cells other than the one it is entered in to. I could do it with one formula by returning the entire list in one cell, but unless we are talking about thousands of cells and it is taking too long to calculate, is there any point?

Answer (score 2):

Use following formula

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$7,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A$1:$A$7)/($B$1:$B$7=$D$1),ROW(1:1))),"")
```

[image]

Comment: this only works, if the source list starts at row 1.

Comment: If your data do not starts from row 1 then you just need little adjustment in formula to work.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, i would just add "Headers" to each column and then use the built-in filter list. The built-in Filter's feature will by far be the most powerful option that anyone will suggest for this.

the Filter options can do the following:

-Sort Items

-Filter Items based on specific values (i.e. what you are looking for)

-Filter based on custom text values

-Filter items based on the cell color

-If the data contains numbers, then it can search for values in between two numbers

-You can also filter by dates

Again VERY POWERFUL TOOL

Before:

[image: Picture of Excel Spread Sheet with Data>Filter's Shown]

After:

[image: Picture of Excel Spread Sheet with Data>Filtere's Shown as Enabled]

Comment: As the goal of the formula usage was to automate this task, using the manual filters is not applicable for my situation.